# PGFPlots (format number)

Tags: pgfplotstable

Me need to get the following converting when PGFPlots will render the table:

```
0.01 -> 0.1 * 10^{-1}

0.121 -> 0.121.

1.843 -> 1.843

10.1 -> 1.01 * 10

124 -> 1.24 * 10^{2}
```

I know about a format option `sci`, but it doesn't help, because it convert, for example, `0.121 to 1.121 * 10^{-1}`.

For example:

[image]

Without `sci` option:
[image]

I want to get it:

[image]

But in each variants, I get a inappropriate result.

Comment: What's the rule? Seems pretty arbitrary and nonstandard to me.

Comment: I has updated question.

Comment: @QueueOverflow But you still didn't explain the rule for how the numbers should be formatted...

Comment: I wrote the rules above. For example: `10.1 -> 1.01 * 10`

Comment: @QueueOverflow What if I write 10.2? What decides whether the result is fixed or sci? IF they are your own then you have to code yourself because these are defined in standards.

Comment: Then you should get `10.2 -> 1.02 * 10`. Are there no options, that can customize format in my style?

Comment: I don't know how else i should put it. You don't define any style. You give 5 numbers and say this should be it. Do you only need these five numbers? Those styles evaluate the number according to some rules and then decide how to typeset them. You are just giving the numbers to guess the rule behind it. Check `std` in the manual of `pgfplotstable` manual for example. Otherwise noone can answer your questions.

Comment: @QueueOverflow There must be something consistent among all the cases to be able to define a consistent style. As it seems right now, the difference between how, e.g. 0.01->0.1E-1, 0.123->0.123 is not clear. Why does one get the power of ten and the other doesn't?

Comment: The difference is determined by definition values of a exponent (lower and upper bound).

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility to set max and min value of exponent, that determine, would number display in a fixed format or a science format:

```
std = <lower e>:<upper e>
```

There is result:

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't lead to the output you wanted, at least according to the third screenshot in your question, where you say you want `0.01` to be formatted as `0.1 * 10^-2`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I apologize for bad example and my inconsistent, I should wrote in my question the following text only: "how to set max and min value of exponent, that determine, would number display in a fixed format or a science format", instead that numerous examples and rules.

Comment: Sorry for the wasting your time :(

Comment: No problem. It's good that you answered your own question after you found the solution! I look forward to your next questions and/or answers; we're all here to learn together, including the best way to ask questions `=)`